# HTML5 Canvas - Repeat Canvas Element as a Pattern

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a 64x64 canvas square element which I want to repeat in x- and y-directions to fill the page. I've found many explanations on how to do this with an image, but none explaining how to do it with a canvas element. Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('dkBg');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
    ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    //I want the following rectangle to be repeated:
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,64,64);
    for(var w=0; w<=64; w++){
            for(var h=0; h<=64; h++){
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
                    while(rand<20){
                            rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
                    }
                    opacity = Math.random();
                    while(opacity<0.5){
                            opacity = Math.random();
                    }
                    ctx.fillStyle= 'rgba('+rand+','+rand+','+rand+','+opacity+')';
                    ctx.fillRect(w,h,1,1);
            }
    }
});
```

The thing is, I **don't** want all of the random numbers/etc to be regenerated. I just want to tile the exact same square to fit the page. Is this possible?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecMDq/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing what you want is actually super easy. You **do not need to use images at all**. The createPattern function accepts an image *or* another canvas! (Or a video tag, even)

All you have to do is make a canvas that is only 64x64 large and make the pattern on it. Let's call this canvas `pattern`. You only have to make your design once.

Then with the context of the main canvas we can do:

```
// "pattern" is our 64x64 canvas, see code in fiddle
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(pattern, "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
```

Working example using your code to make the pattern, then repeating it onto a 500x500 canvas:

http://jsfiddle.net/tGa8M/

Comment: Thanks for this. I chose this answer because it was simpler and seemed like a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the base64 version of your image using the toDataURL() method of the canvas element.

From there it's as simple as setting the background-image of your page to the string `"url(" + base64 + ")"`

Here is a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/ecMDq/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('dkBg');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
    ctx.canvas.width  = 64; //window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = 64; //window.innerHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    //I want the following rectangle to be repeated:
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,64,64);
    for(var w=0; w<=64; w++){
            for(var h=0; h<=64; h++){
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
                    while(rand<20){
                            rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
                    }
                    opacity = Math.random();
                    while(opacity<0.5){
                            opacity = Math.random();
                    }
                    ctx.fillStyle= 'rgba('+rand+','+rand+','+rand+','+opacity+')';
                    ctx.fillRect(w,h,1,1);
            }
    }

    document.documentElement.style.backgroundImage = 
        'url(' +canvas.toDataURL() + ')';

});
```

Note that you need to make the canvas 64x64 because that's the size of your source image.
You can also now make the canvas `display:none`, or even remove it from the dom completely because it's only acting as a source for the background-image.

Also, what on earth is up with those while loops?

```
while(rand<20){
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
}
```

It looks like you're trying to enforce a minimum value. Just use this:

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50-20) + 20);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. While I didn't choose it, I **never** would have thought of doing it like this and I find it very interesting. I might use this technique in the future but at this point I want to keep everything within a canvas tag rather than use a background-image.