# Repeating a method to draw a pattern on 2D Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, html5-canvas

I have a method which draws an image using the context.fillRect() method. I want this image to be drawn repeatedly i.e in a tiled format along the x and y axes as it is small in size (15 pixels in length).

It is to fill my canvas of 700 px width, 500 px height.

Can this be done using the context.createPattern() method? How?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#A_createPattern_example

Answer (score 2):

The secret sauce to using `context.createPattern` is the `context.fillStyle` property.

First, you create the pattern, then you assign the pattern to `context.fillStyle`, and finally, you use `context.fillRect` to draw the pattern:

```
// assuming img is loaded...
var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(img,'repeat');
ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
ctx.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

There is a [complete example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#A_createPattern_example).

Comment: I understand this, but I am not using images. Instead I am drawing various rectangles(ctx.fillRect()) which end up producing an 'image'. Because this image is intended to be small I want it to be drawing hundreds of times to fill up the entire canvas of 700*500px.     http://jsfiddle.net/EP794/42/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to apsillers answer, I would recommend you draw your desired pattern to another canvas element.  You can then pass the completed drawing to `ctx.createPattern`.

```
var drawing = document.createElement('canvas');

//Do necessary drawing
//ctx.fillRect(etc)

var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(drawing,'repeat');
ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
ctx.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

[HTML5 Canvas - Repeat Canvas Element as a Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101613/html5-canvas-repeat-canvas-element-as-a-pattern)